# User's rights to run a service on Vista

Tags: ssh, windows-vista, windows-service, cygwin-sshd

What rights a user needs to run cygwin sshd as a service on vista? A `ssh-host-config` creates user cyg_server with 5 rights:

```
$ editrights.exe -l -u cyg_server
SeAssignPrimaryTokenPrivilege
SeCreateTokenPrivilege
SeTcbPrivilege
SeServiceLogonRight
SeDenyRemoteInteractiveLogonRight
```

But the service failed (even after reboot, reinstall and with cygwin terminal in Administrator mode):

```
$ cygrunsrv.exe -S sshd
Error 1069: The service did not start due to a logon failure
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should verify that the cyg_server account has been correctly set in your "/etc/passwd" file. If you want to be sure, just launch the following command:

```
mkpasswd -l -c >/etc/passwd
```

You should also verify that your new "sshd" service has been registered and will be started by the account "cyg_server":

- Go to the Windows services management interface (Execute --> services.msc)
- Right-click on the sshd service and choose "Properties"
- Verify that the account which is in charge of running the service is "cyg_server"

Perhaps is the following priviledge also necessary:

```
editrights -a SeIncreaseQuotaPrivilege -u cyg_server
```

You can also check in lusrmgr.msc that the account password is set to never expire, and that it hasn't been disabled